# Mercurial: when did this changeset take effect in the stable-branch?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

Scenario: a colleague told me that a bug-fix I made was not in the current build. I said: "but I pushed it 2 weeks ago!"

How can I check that my change (commited into a bug-fix-branch) was merged into the stable-branch and also pushed to the server-repository?

So this really has 3 parts:

1) was it commited? when? See revision number with:

```
hg blame FILENAME
```

see the log with date and so on with:

```
hg log REVISION
```

2) was it merged?

```
hg glog -r "(merge() and branch(2.5) and children(branch('BRANCHNAME')))" \
--template "{branches} [{rev}] ({date|shortdate}): {desc|firstline}\n"
```

Could this be shorter?

3) was it pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shorter and cleaner (under *some conditions*)

**Task 1**

If you can recall any part of any string of you patch-work in any file - `hg help grep`. F.e (pattern is regexp, thus - brackets are escaped for processing "as is"):

```
>hg grep "repo\[None\].parents()" test_hooks.py
tests/test_hooks.py:1417:        state = repo[None].parents()
```

Second field in output (easy parsable for auto-processing) is changeset in which *this change* was made in *this file*

**Task 2**

Just fix for rather dirty (and bad in common logic) revset:

with `merge() and branch(DST) and children(branch('SRC'))` you'll got all mergesets for merging SRC -> DST, even *irrelevant* to known revset of bugfix. Output for the above repository and your revset (note also slightly changed command - `hg glog` is deprecated)

```
>hg log -g -r "(merge() and branch(default) and children(branch('stable')))" --template "{branches} [{rev}] ({date|shortdate}): {desc|firstline}\n"
 [839] (2011-10-19): Merge with stable.
 [841] (2011-10-21): Merge with stable.
 [843] (2011-11-01): Merge with stable
 [982] (2012-11-11): Merge with stable.
 [1021] (2013-06-23): Merge with stable.
 [1108] (2014-02-11): Merge with stable.
 [1126] (2014-02-12): Merge with stable.
 [1171] (2014-04-04): Merge with stable.
 [1180] (2014-05-02): Merge with stable.
 [1228] (2014-08-01): Merge with stable.
 [1231] (2014-08-12): Merge with stable.
 [1257] (2014-11-05): Merge stable back into default.
 [1266] (2014-11-15): Merge with stable.
 [1280] (2014-12-10): Merge with stable.
 [1307] (2015-01-30): Merge with stable.
 [1326] (2015-05-08): Merge stable back into default.
 [1335] (2015-05-29): Merge with stable.
 [1338] (2015-07-08): Merge with stable.
 [1341] (2015-07-09): Merge with stable.
 [1346] (2015-08-11): Merge with stable.
 [1349] (2015-09-26): Merge with stable.
 [1358] (2015-09-30): Merge with stable.
 [1362] (2015-10-21): Merge with stable.
 [1367] (2015-12-31): Merge with stable.
 [1372] (2016-01-27): Merge with stable.
 [1378] (2016-03-04): Merge with stable.
 [1410] (2016-05-11): Merge with stable.
 [1418] (2016-05-23): Merge with stable.
 [1489] (2016-06-26): Merge with stable.
```

I started with plain `descendants(1417)` (greedy revset, yes)

```
>hg log -r "descendants(1417)" -T "{rev}\n"
1417
1418
1419
1420
1421
...
```

because I'm interested in only in merges into `default` (in my case) possible shorter output will be `hg log -r "descendants(1417) and branch(default)"` (but it can be rather long too - I really eliminated two revsets) and only first revset from list  needed

```
>hg log -r "first(descendants(1417) and branch(default))" -T "{rev}\n"
1418
```

Or in a little bit different way (recalling about mergesets entities, can also be first()-ed)

```
>hg log -r "merge() and descendants(1417) and branch(default)" -T "{rev}\n"
1418
1489
```

Notes:

- Solution for p.3 - perform all tests on CENTRAL-REPO clone (which you have already, yes)
- "Bad logic" remark - `branch(2.5) and children(branch('BRANCHNAME')` by design extract only mergesets in 2.5, `merge()` doesn't apply any additional *effective* filter

Addenda:

After some (still unfinished) headache I got the above command as alias with two parameters: problematic changeset and target-branch. It's something like

```
[alias]
ismerged = log -r "first(descendants($1) and branch('$2'))" --template "{ifeq(branch, '$2', 'Merged in {rev}','Not merged')}\n"
```

in repo's `.hgrc`

Output for merged changeset

```
>hg ismerged 62 default
Merged in 63
```

But I can't get else-part to work for not merged changesets and still have dumb empty output in this case

Future (more decorative, than functional) improvements may include:

- transferring revset definition from alias into `[revsetalias]
- getting good else-part of template

Comment: @MayraDelgado - I have to note: 1) my mistake - `hg glog` is `hg log -G` (not `-g`, `-g` is git-compatible log) 2) this command will be more usable as parametrized alias